# How to make separate values the values i took from a dict in python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict = { 44 : ( 43 , 34)}
list.append(dict[44]);
```

It gives me this:

```
[44, (34 , 43)]
```

Although i want `[44 , 34 , 43]` in the new list i have created plz help.

Comment: Please don't use `list` and `dict` as variable names.

Comment: its just to show what i use there its not the real variable names

Comment: It's a bad idea to shadow builtins even in example code, *especially* when it means your code as written (without defining your `list` variable) results in an error: `TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend doing is changing your variable names to something that doesn't clash with built-in types. Then, instead of `append`, you want to use `extend` (or `+=` operator which would do the same thing).

```
l = [44]
d = {44 : (43 , 34)}
l.extend(d[44])
# l += d[44] <-alternate solution
```

Answer (score -3):

```
new_list = new_list + list(your_dict[44]) # assuming new_list is initially [44]
```